# Struts -Hello World - HTTP Status [404]

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am simply trying to created Hello World Struts Application . I have implemented every possible configuration , Still  404 error didnot resolved .

1. My Server config and Project Structure

[image]
[image]

2. Index.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
   <form action="hello">
      <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="name"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

3.HelloWorld.jsp

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   Hello World, <s:property value="name"/>
</body>
</html>
```

4.struts.xml

```html
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">
     
      <action name="hello" 
            class=".HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

5.web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   
   <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

5.HelloWorldAction.java Class

```html
public class HelloWorldAction{
   private String name;

   public String execute() throws Exception {
      return "success";
   }
   
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

What can I modify to get a clue whats going wrong ??

Comment: what is that struts.xml  file you specified, its same as HelloWorld.jsp?  I didn't understand.

Comment: edited ............

Comment: how did you configure the struts.xml path in web.xml. Im not well versed with Struts 2

Comment: there must be some deployment errors printed out in your console ... post them here too...

Comment: Also what is that `.HelloWorldAction` in your `struts.xm` where is the class?

Comment: i have put helloWorld Action Class , and nothing is showing in console after messege "server is started" . is there any log file generated ?

Comment: I am not sure about your `struts.xml`  syntax - e.g. the dot before class name. Look for warnings / errors in tomcat's log file....

Comment: Can you suggest where that log file exists

Comment: just a SO tip - you should put @user to address someone - so that he / she gets notification of your response (unless u r responding inside someone's post) ... tomcat logs are usually located inside log folder of tomcat root directory ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a package and move HelloWorldAction.java and Product.java to that package (Good Practice).Then specify path in `struts.xml`
like: - package name demo.struts

```
 <action name="hello" class="demo.struts.HelloWorldAction"  method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

Change `Struts.xml` to `struts.xml`